# How to get PNG format icon as a attribute in custom component (HarmonyOS)

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am creating a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK, Where I need one attribute to get Element(i.e. VectorElement or png format icon) as input from xml layout file.

for ex:

```
ohos:sliderIcon="$graphic:custom_icon" (VectorElement)
ohos:sliderIcon="$media:ic_arrow"      (PNG format icon)
```

Now I am getting element in custom component class like this

```
Element sliderIcon = attrSet.getAttr(Attribute.SLIDER_ICON).isPresent()
                    ? attrSet.getAttr(Attribute.SLIDER_ICON).get().getElement()
                    : new VectorElement(getContext(), ResourceTable.Graphic_slidetoact_ic_arrow);
```

but, above code is working only for VectorElement icon NOT for PNG format icon.

And I am able to set both VectorElement and PNG format icon at runtime from java code as follow:

For VectorElement:

```
Element sliderIcon = new VectorElement(getContext(), ResourceTable.Graphic_custom_icon);
```

For PNG format icon:

```
//You can set png format icon using PixelMapElement.
     try {
            Element sliderIcon = new PixelMapElement(getResourceManager().getResource(ResourceTable.Media_ic_arrow));
     } catch (IOException | NotExistException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

So my question is

**How to get PNG format icon as a attribute in custom component?**

OR

**How to get resource/reference id of passed Element?**

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your method to get `pixelMap` through `PixelMapElement`,

```
PixelMapElement pixelMapElement = (PixelMapElement) attrSet.getAttr("sliderIcon").get().getElement();
PixelMap pixelMap = pixelMapElement.getPixelMap();
```

Tested in the `onDraw` method and proved to be available.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Component component, Canvas canvas) {
    PixelMapHolder pixelMapHolder = new PixelMapHolder(pixelMap);
    canvas.drawPixelMapHolder(pixelMapHolder,0,0,new Paint());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Element sliderIcon = attrSet.getAttr(Attribute.SLIDER_ICON).isPresent()
                    ? attrSet.getAttr(Attribute.SLIDER_ICON).get().getElement()
                    : new VectorElement(getContext(), ResourceTable.Graphic_slidetoact_ic_arrow);
```

This solution is working for both type of element VectorElement and PixleMapElement(PNG format icon).
It's my bad I am not doing it properly, I did mistake in xml file `ohos:sliderIcon="$Media:ic_arrow"`
we have to use small **m** in media.
like this
`ohos:sliderIcon="$media:ic_arrow"`